After aws rds snapshot restore with different endpoint can't connect
I would like to ask why, after restoring a snapshot in RDS and naming it differently, I am unable to connect. The original instance was named 'mysql8', and after the restoration, it became 'mysql8-test'.
Does anyone know the reason for this?
I am using MySQL Workbench to connect, but still unable to establish a connection. What should I do to troubleshoot this?
I have confirmed that the VPC is the same as before, but the only difference is that the endpoint address has changed.

The first thing to always check is the Security Group inbound rules. Also, are you accessing the database from a computer on the Internet, or from an EC2 instance in the same VPC? Is the database set to Publicly Accessible = Yes? Was it launched in a Public Subnet or a Private Subnet? Compare all the differences between the instances and you'll eventually identify the cause.
